# Eager Loading, Constraining Eager Loads, Lazy Eager Loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel, and I'm using Laravel 5.2. I want to know about Eager Loading, Constraining Eager Loads, and Lazy Eager Loading. What are the similarities and differences between those three? Can you give an example for each of them? I have read Laravel documentation, but I still don't understand. I hope you can give clearer explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nutshell:

`Eager Loading` allows you to get the relationships for some Models efficiently.

`Constraining Eager Loads` Again makes it efficient, but you can limit your results e.g. date range, specific ID etc

`Lazy Eager Loading` Is for when you already have your parent models loaded

Example:

Ok, lets say you're making a Blog where you will have Posts and those post can have comments and likes.

Scenario 1:

You want to get all the `Posts` with their `Comments` and their `Likes`. Would you load all the `Post` and then loop through them and get their `comments` and `likes`? Well, you could but this could end up being very expensive as it could end up performing many, many queries. Or you could load the posts and then get their `id`s and load all the comments that you need for those `id`s and the same for their likes as well. This is essentially what `Laravel` does with eager loading.

Scenario 2 (a real world example of Scenario 1):

You're creating you feed for the posts. So, you've loaded up all your Posts, and then you want to show how many likes and comments it has, so you would have something like (very basic):

Controller:

```
$posts = App\Post::all();

return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
```

blade file:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
   
    <h2>{{ $post->title }}</h2>
   
    <p>{{ $post->description }}</p>
   
    <p>
        Likes: {{ $post->likes->count() }} <br>
        Comments: {{ $post->comments->count() }}
    </p>
   
@endforeach
```

The above would work but for every loop it would actually be querying the database. Changing your controller to:

```
$posts = App\Post::with('likes', 'comments')->get();

return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
```

Will then get the `comments` and `likes` for all of the `Posts` beforehand saving the database and making your application much more efficient.

Scenario 3

I want to show the `Posts` but I only want to show the last 3 `comments` that were made.

```
$posts = App\Post::with(['comments' => function ($query) {

        $query->limit(3);

    }]);
```

`Lazy Eager Loading` is for when you've already loaded your `Posts` and you then need to get all the `comments` or `likes` after the fact. Same principle but you would use `load` instead of `with`. Another reason you might use load is if you using `Route model binding` for your controllers so the `Post` will have already been retrieved, but you still want to get its relationships.

Hope this help!

Comment: Well, I don't really get it. Because, in all of your examples, I can use limitation / constraint for what I want to be loaded. So, is that limitation become the similarity between them? Then, what is the difference? Sorry, I'm still new in this subject

Comment: @GraceMichelle Yeah, that's pretty much it. If you want to constrain them you can be you don't have to. The main different is between `eager loading` and `lazy eager loading` - the former is for when you're loading the parents as well and the latter is for when the parents are already loaded.

Comment: Is there another similarity? Ok, I know about those two difference. Then, what is the difference between those two and `constraint eager loads`?

Comment: `constraint eager loads` allows you to limit the queries down i.e. like adding a `where` clause to a query. So, if you want to get all the models for a relationship you don't add a constraints, if you do want to limit them somehow then you add those constraints.

Comment: Ok. So, I use all of them in order to make a more efficient load, right?

Comment: Thanks for your help :)